# saving NSMutableArray of object to pList

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, plist

I'm trying to save an array of objects to pList when the home button or program is exited, but nothing happen and the file never seems to be created.

What am I doing wrong????

//ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *fieldBooks;

- (NSString *)pathOfFile;
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification;

@end
```

//ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *filePath = [self pathOfFile];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        fieldBooks = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:app];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Instantiate our NSMutableArray

    //Set title
    self.title = @"FieldBooks";

    //Add edit button
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    //Add the add button
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [myTableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}

- (void)insertNewObject
{
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter name" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert show];
}

- (NSString *)pathOfFile
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsFolder = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentsFolder stringByAppendingFormat:@"myFile.plist"];
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [array addObject:fieldBooks];
    [array writeToFile:[self pathOfFile] atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDocumentationDirectory
```

Hm. I'm sure you meant

```
NSDocumentDirectory
```

instead.